# Application 'cannot connect to database' exception

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x, cloudbees

When I try to deploy a Play! Framework (v1.2.4) app to cloudbees using the Play! Framework cloudbees plugin I get the following exception

Exception in thread "main" play.exceptions.DatabaseException: Cannot connected to the database, Access denied for user ''@'' (using password: YES)

If I try to connect to the database using a client (e.g. Navicat for MySQL Lite) I also get an access denied error.

Deployments and connections to the database have been working fine up until today.

Comment: I think that you have an error in the connection Url. Please show some config.

Comment: Just heard from cloudbees support - looks like there is a problem with creating new databases at the moment and I had recently dropped and recreated the database

Comment: yes there was a temporary problem with new databases

Answer (score 0):

> Access denied for user ''@'

seems to demonstrate a lack of username set for your connection.